# Google Apps SAML2 behavior with external users

Tags: google-apps, saml-2.0

When we enable SAML2 SSO with google apps - we expect our users external to google apps to login via an external SAML2 IdP. But - it looks like Google has a limitation - where, even though authentication happens at the external SAML2 Idp - that particular users name should be present in Google Apps user store it self. Why do we see this limitation in Google Apps ? This will require all users been provisioned to Google Apps. Ideally we would expect users from out login to Google Apps via SAML2.

Answer (score 2):

This is true - and there are many options for adding users to Google Apps.  See: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179832&topic=14586&ctx=topic

If you have a local AD server, the sync tool from Google should suit.  Some federation products, like PingFederate, also have this capability (E.g.: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/marketplace-integration-details?recordId=a7i1W0000004ID9QAM - Disclaimer I work for Ping).